# Displaying Google Map within service using window manager system service

Tags: android, google-maps, service, window-managers

In my app I need to be able to display google map as overlay up on other applications.

For doing so I am using service and window manager to show google map view as TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT .

I am already able to the display the map twice inside the activity using 2 different google API clients with same valid API key.

I can't figure it out but for some reason when attaching the 'View' which contains 'SupportMapFragment' to 'WindowManager' the map wont display , only google logo at the bottom .

I was thinking maybe it has to do something with pixel format ?
Any suggestions ?

It has to do something with kind of views which window manager supporting , maybe window manager cannot display fragments ?

Is it possible to archive what am I trying to ?

- There is no problem in the implementation so I don't past code here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maybe window manager cannot display fragments ?

Correct. [Use `MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) directly. It may not work especially well in your case, as not everything is designed to go in an alert window, but it is the only chance that you have.

Also note that your app may have problems starting with Android O, as Google slowly starts to rein in apps that do these sorts of overlays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I was trying with MapView also same results ):

Comment: Going to try WebView  with java-script Google Map API (: